# Error while using ConvertJSONToSQL processor in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using 2.5 HDP. I got issue in ConvertJSONToSQL processor I try to convert bulk(1GB) size of Avro file into SQL format,for that first I convert Avro format into JSON format (by using ConvertAvroToJSON processor) after that I convert JSON format into SQL format (by using ConvertJSONToSQL processor) that time I got issue that I mention below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

First you try to split bulk size of Avro format file into some small size by using SplitAvro processor which is present in Nifi and then you convert it into json

Configure processor of SplitAvro processor

[image: configure processor of SplitAvro processor]

For more information follow this [link](https://help.syncfusion.com/data-integration/processors/splitavro)